# R.java not generated after update

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

My generation of R.java is non-existent, but my BuildConfig.java is still generated when projects are rebuilt. This problem is not localized to a single project in my workspace, but to the entire workspace which has projects in ranging from gingerbread to jb, all of which exhibit this error. I have been working with the Android platform for over a year now, and the R.java generation has always been a little mystical, but would always seem to fix itself with a restart of eclipse or a rebuild of the project.

This started when I ran a java update to java 7, so did a changed back to the java 6 sdk, specifically 1.6.0_26, did a fresh install of eclipse(4.2), the android sdk and adt, but to no effect.

I am working on this project with other group members(working off of the same master git repo), and they are not having problems with R.java generating, so therefore I can say for certainty that there are no errors in files causing the R.java to not generate.

And as a disclaimer, yes I have read the plethora of material on here with R.java related issues.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same symptoms.

### Problem

- `R.java` not getting build across the workspace, resulting in an error when trying to import it:

  ```
  The import <tld>.<project>.R cannot be resolved
  ```
- The error reporting that the version of `adb` could not be determined despite existing:

  ```
  Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/dtk/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory from '/home/dtk/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb' - exists=true`
  ```

  ```
  dtk@humbee ~/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools % ll | grep adb
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 dtk dtk 200K Sep 12 14:41 adb*
  dtk@humbee ~/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools % file adb
  adb: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
  dtk@humbee ~/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools % ./adb
  zsh: no such file or directory: ./adb
  127 dtk@humbee ~/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools %
  ```

### Solution

Installing `ia32-libs` fixed it for me:

```
root@humbee:~# uname -m
x86_64
root@humbee:~# aptitude search ia32-libs
p   ia32-libs                                                                                                     - ia32 shared libraries for use on amd64 and ia64 systems                                                                 
p   ia32-libs-dev                                                                                                 - ia32 development files for use on amd64 and ia64 systems                                                                
p   ia32-libs-gtk                                                                                                 - GTK+ ia32 shared libraries                                                                                              
v   ia32-libs-static                                                                                              -                                                                                                                         
root@humbee:~# aptitude install ia32-libs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ia32-libs lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32tinfo5{a} lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc6-i386{a} 
    [...]
```

```
dtk@humbee ~/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools % ./adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
dtk@humbee ~/.opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools %
```

HTH,
dtk

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, I would recommend to turn-on extended logging, it should display AAPT output, when AAPT is a tool for generating R.java.

To make this - go to Window->Preference->Android->Build and set BuildOutput to Verbose.
When you are done - make a clean build and pay a highest attention on COnsoleOutput tab in Eclipse. Every warning or message can guide you to the error.

Let us know if you'll notice something interesting.

Good luck

Comment: Ah thanks, I forgot to mention that I did do that already. There is an error from earlier:                                       "Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/brent/SDKs/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory from '/home/brent/SDKs/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb' - exists=true"                                                         but that only showed up once. Additionally, the file is there at the path located, and has the following permissions:-rwxrwxr-x

Comment: And as I understand, /home/brent/SDKs/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb actually exist?
Does it have -x(Execute) permissions?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous post, but yes it does exist and have permissions to be executed by anyone

Comment: Yeah I am really stuck, and nope that was the only one.

Comment: Does executing "/home/brent/SDKs/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb devices" in the terminal works? Just to ensure adb is ok

Comment: Hmm, no it seems like issuing a ./adb yields a "no such file or directory error." Odd, I am in the same directory as it is and it clearly states that is is an executable :/

Comment: Ok, so I suggest 2 solutions:
Scheck is the ADB is a real executable, not a symlink. If it is a symlink - make sure it points to the good working ADB with necessary right.
If it will not help - can you try to update your platform tools with SDK Manager? Hope you are not using latest ones. If you are - I'll recommend to remove platform tools and download from scratch, it should not do any harm, if you didn't modified them.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this with the latest update. **Deleting** then **re-importing** the project to my workspace fixed it.